# Static class member of normal class

Tags: java, oop

Say I have something like this:

```
public class Foo {

  public static class Bar {}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Foo f = new Foo();
  }
}
```

my question is - does the class exist as a `Class<T>` member of the `Foo` instance `f`? What exactly happens here? From my experimentation, it looks like you can access it like Foo.Bar, but I don't think the `f` instance sees the class. So this appears to be more like a *namespacing* utility.

Comment: [Why Use Nested Classes?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: You are right at "this appears to be more like a namespacing utility". And Foo.Bar (as a class, but not as an instance of Bar) is valid but f.Bar is not.